# Вывести на экран елку такого размера, который вы указали?

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать вот такую елку:

```
        *
       ***
      *****
        *
```

А у меня получаеться просто треугольник:

```
var i = 0, j = 0;
var max = prompt('Enter size');
var emptiness = "", stars = "";

while (i < max) {
  emptiness = "";
  stars = "";
for (j = 0; j < max - i; j++) emptiness += " ";
for (j = 0; j < 2 * i + 1; j++) stars += "*";
console.log(emptiness + stars);
  i++;
}
```

Получаеться вот такой треугольник:

```
        *
       ***
      *****
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам осталось добавить после главного цикла одну начальную его итерацию, обнулив перед этим переменные:

```js
var i = 0, j = 0;
var max = prompt('Enter size');
var emptiness = "", stars = "";

while (i < max) {
  emptiness = "";
  stars = "";
  for (j = 0; j < max - i; j++) emptiness += " ";
  for (j = 0; j < 2 * i + 1; j++) stars += "*";
  console.log(emptiness + stars);
  i++;
}

emptiness = "", stars = "", i = 0;
for (j = 0; j < max - i; j++) emptiness += " ";
for (j = 0; j < 2 * i + 1; j++) stars += "*";
console.log(emptiness + stars);
```